# Matching with & operator

Tags: ruby

Why does this occur?

```
words = ['molly', 'fish', 'sally']
cats = ['sally', 'molly']
matches = words & cats
```

My research indicates ampersand is a bitwise operator. why would it have this effect?

Comment: Why would it have what effect?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26

Comment: [Fixnum@#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-26) is a bitwise operator; [Array#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26) is array intersection. Is `&`'s receiver here (`words`) a fixnum or an array?

Comment: This is a basic speed-bump when learning about object-oriented programming, and especially when learning using Ruby's documentation. You have to look at the class of the objects being used. `words` and `cats` are Arrays, so, though normally `&` is used how you think, classes can implement some operators differently, in ways that make sense to that particular use. As others said, `&` in the context of an Array is an intersection, and you could tell that it was used that way because `words` is an Array instance, and, hence, you should look in that class's documentation.

Comment: In Ruby, many "operators" are really methods, not language keywords, and have class-specific behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Class `Array` has on it defined a method called `:&`:

> [].class.method_defined?(:&)
>
> => true

This calls the underlying C-code:

```
               static VALUE
rb_ary_and(VALUE ary1, VALUE ary2)
{
    VALUE hash, ary3, v;
    st_table *table;
    st_data_t vv;
    long i;

    ary2 = to_ary(ary2);
    ary3 = rb_ary_new();
    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary2) == 0) return ary3;
    hash = ary_make_hash(ary2);
    table = rb_hash_tbl_raw(hash);

    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary1); i++) {
        v = RARRAY_AREF(ary1, i);
        vv = (st_data_t)v;
        if (st_delete(table, &vv, 0)) {
            rb_ary_push(ary3, v);
        }
    }
    ary_recycle_hash(hash);

    return ary3;
}
```

This checks for all shared values within the two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Array Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-26); `#&` is an intersection between two arrays.

> Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, excluding any duplicates. The order is preserved from the original array.
>
> It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is an array function that returns the intersection.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-26

```
ary & other_ary → new_ary 
Set Intersection — Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, excluding any duplicates. The order is preserved from the original array.

It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.

[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]                 #=> [ 1, 3 ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'z' ] & [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]   #=> [ 'a', 'b' ]
See also #uniq.
```